# How do I determine if my knife must be honed and/or sharpened?

Tags: discussion

I don't think [How do I determine if my knife must be honed and/or sharpened?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/102476/24882) duplicates [How to test that a knife is sharp enough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3928/24882)?

In the former, I'm asking when to use a honing steel vs. a whetstone/electronic sharpener.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, when reading both questions back-to-back I can see why people would mark your question as a duplicate because you can infer the answer to your question from "[How to test that a knife is sharp enough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3928/how-to-test-that-a-knife-is-sharp-enough)?" pretty easily. This inference, and learning could be done (and really should) as part of your preliminary research as per [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

While, there are differences to the questions - there really aren't enough to justify a whole new question. Combine that with the plethora of resources online about knives, knife care & maintenance and basic techniques. I can see why you got the result you did.

And if rumstcho added a comment about being a "possible duplicate" I would've up voted it for the reasons I stated, as I don't have the privileged to do it myself yet.